# Jquery $.get is not internally parsing json response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
  $.get("api/suites", function(result){
    console.log("the suites get api result is of type - " + typeof result)
    console.log("the list of custom suites are " + result)
  }, "json")
```

It prints,

```
  the suites get api result is of type - string
  the list of custom suites are "{\"suites\":[\"h\",\"b\"]}"
```

Check response headers with curl -

```
curl -v -X GET http://localhost:8002/api/suites
```

shows,

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
"{\"suites\":[\"h\",\"b\"]}"
```

Why doesn't $.get convert the json data into an object, before calling the callback function?

I tried the same with ajax call instead of $.get, but still the callback gets a string.

```
  $.ajax({"url": "api/suites", "method": "GET", "dataType": "json", headers: {     Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8" }})
```

Comment: @Nathan that's just  hack for fixing the actual problem because it should already be parsed internally by jQuery `$.ajax

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry about that - deleted the comment! Somebody should really study jQuery docs... :-)

Comment: you have extra quotes...the response shouldn't have external quotes around `{}`. So you have json in json. Problem is at server output

Comment: oh, got it.. charlietfl.. i was serializing my server side response using `JSON.stringify`. now, i passed object to express's `res.send`. it works well. thanks a lot, man

Comment: @charlietfl, can you make it an answer..so that i can mark it as accepted.. others may not have to revisit this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the response has extra quotes wrapping the json representation of the object...making it `json in json` string (for lack of a better description)

Remove the extra quotes at server that are wrapping the outer `{}` so that it is valid to convert to object

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does that automatically.  Not sure if you're making a call to your own API but the API you're requesting is returning the response in string format.  The following should work:

```
result = JSON.parse(result)
```

Comment: I would think so - but check charliefl's comment in the question. He says that jQuery should automatically parse the result...

Comment: `don't think it doesn't that automatically` ...read the docs...it does and should be in this instance when dataType is set and when header is correct

Comment: I've used AJAX in the same way and have always had to parse the response when it's in string format, even if it's a string of JSON data and I have the response marked as JSON in the AJAX call.

Comment: Hrm...  jQuery doc says this about the dataType parameter: `The type of data expected from the server.`  Not sure where in the docs you're seeing it but I don't see any mention that it automatically parses JSON.  Also, I know from personal experience working with AJAX that responses in string format aren't automatically parsed, even if the data is JSON as a string.

Comment: @JohnHalbert I have worked with jQuery ajax and json since version 1.08 and never once had to parse a response. Copied straight from docs `"json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object.`

Comment: @charlietfl - so, and not to make a stink, but "evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object" doesn't mean it converts from a string to a JavaScript object.  It means it takes JSON and converts to a JavaScript object, which JSON is not, in fact.  Madhavan above mentions that he used JSON.stringify on the server side before sending the response.  This means he took his JSON data and converted it to string format and sent that as his response.  AJAX is expecting JSON data, not string data.  It doesn't parse string data or convert it to JSON or a JavaScript object.

Comment: @JohnHalbert it will be string if don't set dataType or have content-type headers as application/json. But OP had both so that made it apparent that the problem was invalid data structure

Comment: right...but fixing the source so the intended behavior of the data parsing makes more sense than throwing a band aid on it. What was delivered was not what was expected

Comment: `The problem is that the response has extra quotes wrapping the json representation of the object...making it json in json (for lack of a better description)` This makes it a string. :)

Comment: `but fixing the source`...`makes more sense than throwing a band aid on it` Yup! But I wasn't sure that he was making the call to his own API or an external one...  If it was the later then he would have no choice.

Comment: agree about the string...for sure...but that was not what was expected. It was an obvious errror. imagine exposing that as a public api then telling people...you have to also parse it ...and if you use native XMLHttpRequest...parse it twice!